# JavaScript Safari issue with setting data attribute

Tags: javascript, html

In order to deal with responsive images, I'm displaying images using the correct data attribute according to the current window width. So e.g. if my window width is larger than my settings.desktop var value, whatever is currently in the data-lrg attribute is displayed as an image.

The following JavaScript code works in all recent browsers, except in Safari where the data attribute of the images can't be set, or so it seems.

My JS-fu isn't exactly up to par, which means I'm not 100% sure what I'm doing. Does anybody know of any Safari quirks related to settings data attributes?

Markup:

```
<img class="data-img" data-xsml="width_460_height_345.jpg" data-sml="width_670_height_503.jpg" data-med="width_437_height_328.jpg" data-lrg="width_288_height_216.jpg" alt="alt tag" src="width_288_height_216.jpg">
```

My JavaScript:

```
$.fn.dataImg = function(options) {
   var settings = $.extend({
   mobile: 506,
   tablet: 725,
   desktop: 945
}, options );
var elements = $(this);

function getSrc(element) {
   var screen = $(window).width();
   if (screen >= settings.desktop) { 
       return element.data('lrg');
   }
   else if (screen < settings.desktop && screen >= settings.tablet) {
       return element.data('med');
   }
   else if (screen < settings.tablet && screen >= settings.mobile) {
       return element.data('sml');
   }
   else {
      return element.data('xsml');
   }
}
function breakpoints() {
  elements.each(function () {
    var e = $(this);
    var src = getSrc(e);
    if(src != undefined){
        if (e.is('img')) {
            e.attr('src', src);
        } else {
            e.css('background-image', 'url(' + src + ')');
        }
    }        
});
}breakpoints();

if(settings.resize == true){
     $(window).resize(function(){
       breakpoints();
     });
    }

 };
```

Comment: Do you mean Safari for Windows or Mac?

Comment: For both Windows and Mac, not sure if that's good or bad. Tested on multiple systems with the exact same outcome, images do not resize as expected.

Comment: Can you provide a test case on jsfiddle?

Comment: For some odd reason it does work in this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gfg25aud/2/

Comment: tested on Safari, your code seem working.

Comment: That's great! Thank you both very much for testing & feedback! I take it I may have something else going on in my script file that's causing trouble.

Comment: Also FYI this check `screen < settings.desktop` is useless since it's not `screen >= settings.desktop`

Comment: Ah yes, good point. Thank you for noticing that!

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a CSS or markup error which was most likely caused by incorrect usage of the framework used. Somehow Safari handled things differently than other browsers. the My bad!